# Mi imagen no se muestra correctamente

Tags: html, css

Tengo una imagen en css como fondo pero aunque la elimine se sigue mostrando, quiero cambiarla pero la nueva imagen no se muestra.

este es el codigo de la imagen nueva que quiero poner

```
body{
    background:url(../imagenes/real.jpg);
}
```

este es el código de la anterior imagen

```
body{
    background:url(../imagenes/fondo2.png);
}
```

Comment: Por favor replantea tu problema porque no se entiende que es el problema. La sintaxis se ve bien. Aúnque falta algunos detalles. Te sugiero que copies bien la ruta de tu imagen, y agregues los demás declaraciones del background

Comment: Y como ya lo has corregido, te cargas la pregunta para que no pueda servir de ayuda a nadie más, no? Aquí estamos para servirte a tí y al resto del mundo que les den, tú ya tienes lo que quieres y el conocimiento y tiempo que se haya invertido en tu pregunta que no sirva de nada, no vaya a ser que ayudemos a más de una persona a la vez! Haz el favor y respeta a toda la gente que invierte su tiempo en ayudar de manera **GRATUITA**, y no borres/edites las preguntas una vez resueltas. Pon la solución como respuesta a tu pregunta, márcala como aceptada y listo.

Comment: Que tal todo? si no se muestra lo mas seguro es que tengas un formato diferente es decir tu primer imagen es .jpg la otra debe tener otro formato, o te estas equivocando en el nombre. otra cosita para llamar imagen usa `background-image:;` es mala practica usa el `background` ya que esto utiliza todas las propiedades del ``background` Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Si se sigue mostrando la anterior, probablemente se haya quedado en la caché del navegador. Para que se muestre la actual, tendrías que refrescar la caché con CTRL + F5 en Windows o CMD + R en Mac.